# pre_get_posts for products on category page - woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to filter the products on a category products so that it shows only the products of a certain author or multiple authors.

I already have the following code. This works as it filters the products. The correct products are displayed. Except the Woocommerce filters on in the left sidebar are not affected by the filter. The filters on the left side are showing all the original products in the category (also from other users) so the count isn't correct and also attributes from products that are filtered are showing. This shouldn't be the case. Do I have to add another pre_get_posts for the filters?

```
 <?php
function pre_get_posts_by_author( $q ) {


    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
    if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

    $cat_obj = $q->get_queried_object();

    if($cat_obj->name == 'Nieuw')
    {   
        $q->set( 'author_ids',  '2086,2084');   
    }


}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'pre_get_posts_by_author' );


add_filter( 'posts_where', 'author_posts_where', 10, 2 );
function author_posts_where( $where, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;


    if ( $wp_query->get( 'author_ids' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_author IN (' . $wp_query->get( 'author_ids' ) .')';
    }
    return $where;
}
?>
```

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 2):

Probabaly a better way to do this is by setting 'author__in' argument in your query which will take an array of authors the query will return products of.

```
function pre_get_posts_by_author( $q ) {


    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() || !$q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

    $cat_obj = $q->get_queried_object();

    if( $cat_obj->name == 'Nieuw' ){

        $q->set( 'author__in',  array(2086,2084)); 

    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'pre_get_posts_by_author' );
```

Answer (score -1):

My updated solution: still dirty as it modifies Woocommerce's core files (2.2.4), but it works:

in the `pre_get_posts`-hook I retrieve the ids of the products I want to exclude with the following code:

```
$_SESSION['total_excluded'] = get_objects_in_term( $term_ids, $taxonomies, $args )`
```

(reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_objects_in_term)

Then in `woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-layered-nav.php` I changed line 258 to:

```
$count = sizeof( array_diff(array_intersect( $_products_in_term, WC()->query->filtered_product_ids) , $_SESSION['total_excluded'] ) );
```

In `woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-price-filter.php` the new lines 121, 136 are:

```
%1$s.ID IN (' . implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', array_diff(WC()->query->layered_nav_product_ids, $_SESSION['total_excluded']  ) ) ) . ')
```

In `woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-price-filter.php` the new lines 123, 138 are:

```
%1$s.post_parent IN (' . implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', array_diff(WC()->query->layered_nav_product_ids, $_SESSION['total_excluded'] ) ) ) . ')
```

Comment: Note: My Layered Nav Widget is set to AND. If you use OR, u'd have to adapt the code of woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-layered-nav.php on line 269 accordingly. Also: I am not quite sure what the case in woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-price-filter.php on line 94 means. Is this the case if you use only the price filter? I haven't modified that part because it didn't change my results.